# How to use the redux-persist persisted store to update other reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with react-redux and the react-persist npm module. I've successfully configured the module so that each type the page refreshes, the `persist/REHYDRATE` action is called and handled by one of my reducers. I'm able to save this old state on its own. My questions is: how do I merge this state with the states of my other reducers?

I currently have the persist reducer in the combine reducers method so that I can easily view it in the console (I'm aware that this isn't the correct solution).

reducers/index.js:

```
...
export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  data:dataReducer,
  persist:persistReducer,
});
```

reducers/persistReducer.js:

```
export default(state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PERSIST_REHYDRATE:
      console.log("hit persisted state");
      return {...state, persistedState: action.payload}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

How do I, for example, get the user from the persisted state and update the `userReducer` value with it? Should I be doing that in the persistReducer? Something else?